# speeding up Spacy using Cython

Tags: python, nlp, cython, spacy

Recently I've been reading some posts on writing code in Cython in order to achieve better performance for NLP purposes and I got a bit confused. https://medium.com/huggingface/100-times-faster-natural-language-processing-in-python-ee32033bdced for instance, here they use Cython to loop over doc elements and count entries of specific words;

```
cdef struct DocElement:
TokenC* c
int length

cdef int fast_loop(DocElement* docs, int n_docs, hash_t word, hash_t tag):
    cdef int n_out = 0
    for doc in docs[:n_docs]:
        for c in doc.c[:doc.length]:
            if c.lex.lower == word and c.tag == tag:
                n_out += 1
    return n_out

def main_nlp_fast(doc_list):
    cdef int i, n_out, n_docs = len(doc_list)
    cdef Pool mem = Pool()
    cdef DocElement* docs = <DocElement*>mem.alloc(n_docs, sizeof(DocElement))
    cdef Doc doc
    for i, doc in enumerate(doc_list): # Populate our database structure
        docs[i].c = doc.c
        docs[i].length = (<Doc>doc).length
    word_hash = doc.vocab.strings.add('run')
    tag_hash = doc.vocab.strings.add('NN')
    n_out = fast_loop(docs, n_docs, word_hash, tag_hash)
    print(n_out)
```

that approach results in significantly better speed compared to pure Python, but this example assumes that we've got Doc object created previously. But creating Doc from plain text is the part where I already get a rather slow program for not very long documents (roughly the same size they mention in the post), even if I remove everything except Tokenizer from the pipeline. Is there a way to speed up this process using Cython? I don't know if my question makes any sense, but I really need some clarification on the subject

Comment: Please edit your post to include all of the relevant info within the question, so that it can be understood without visiting an external link. External links are ok to provide additional context, but shouldn't be necessary to understand a question or answer - if a linked website later ceased to exist, the post would no longer be useful.